# File sending from multiple client to Single server in Java Socket Programming

Tags: java, sockets

hi i am trying to create a program in java for sending files from multiple client to single server. is this is possible?

i tried this could for multiple client and single server and also it is from server to client sending program.

Client Program

```
public class Client {

    public Client(String ip,String path,int i) throws IOException {

        int filesize=2022386;
        int bytesRead;
        int currentTot = 0;

        File file=new File(path);
        File dir=new File("c:/PAMR/Dest"+i+"/");
        String name=file.getName();

        if(!dir.exists())
        {
            dir.mkdir();
        }

        Socket socket = new Socket(ip,9100);
        byte [] bytearray  = new byte [filesize];
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();


        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dir+"/"+name);

        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bytesRead = is.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);


        currentTot = bytesRead;

        do {
            bytesRead =
              is.read(bytearray, currentTot, (bytearray.length-currentTot));
           if(bytesRead >= 0) currentTot += bytesRead;


        } while(bytesRead > -1);


        bos.write(bytearray, 0 , currentTot);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        socket.close();

    }



}
```

for Server

```
public class Source {


    public  Source(String path) throws IOException {

           ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9100);
           System.out.println("Server is in Listening Mode");
           Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

           File transferFile = new File (path);

           byte [] bytearray  = new byte [(int)transferFile.length()];
           FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(transferFile);
           BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);

           bin.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
           OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();



           os.write(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
           bin.close();
           os.close();
           os.flush();
           socket.close();
           serverSocket.close();


     }


}
```

it is a part of code for my project i am doing.

Any body pls help.

Comment: Use [Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html). One for each connected client

Comment: @BackSladh, hi thnks for replying immediately. do i need to create threads at client side?, how do i get the name of file what i send from client, at server.

Comment: No you don't, you need to use Threads server-side, as shown by Martin Dinov in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
boolean working = true;
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(9100);
while(working) {
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        MyThread myThread = new MyThread(s);
        myTread.start();
}
```

where `MyThread` is a class of yours that extends the `Thread` class, accepts the connection to the client that just connected and then accepts any file or data sent to it.